# SQL formatting to "user friendly date"

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I've got the following SQL to output a pretty version of working dates:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(day(tbl_contract_dates.date) SEPARATOR ', ') as days,
       DATE_FORMAT(tbl_contract_dates.date, '%M') as month,
       DATE_FORMAT(tbl_contract_dates.date, '%Y') as year
FROM tbl_contract_dates 
WHERE tbl_contract_dates.contract_id = 34
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tbl_contract_dates.date, '%M %Y') 
ORDER BY tbl_contract_dates.date;
```

This will output something like this:

```
+--------------------+-----------+------+
| days               | month     | year |
+--------------------+-----------+------+
| 8, 10, 11, 12, 16  | August    | 2020 |
| 20, 27, 28, 29, 30 | September | 2020 |
| 1, 2               | October   | 2020 |
+--------------------+-----------+------+
```

I can't find, if it is at all possible, a way to get my days as:

```
+--------------+-----------+------+
| days         | month     | year |
+--------------+-----------+------+
| 8, 10-12, 16 | August    | 2020 |
| 20, 27-30    | September | 2020 |
| 1-2          | October   | 2020 |
+--------------+-----------+------+
```

I need to get continuous numbers to simply be replaced with a '-' as you can see.

Can this me achieved in SQL / MySQL ? Running MySQL 5.5.28. I know it's old, but that's what I've got and can't upgrade... :(

Thanks for your inputs!
Pat

Comment: can you create a fiddle with sample data, so we can try on that?

Comment: Not sure I understand how I'd create a fiddle playground...  I can't open up access to my DB to the outside world ;)

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: The easiest way may be  to write a function that takes the current result string and outputs the final string. (If MySQL functions are capable of doing this; I do't know.) Otherwise you'd end up with a gaps & islands problem, which you could solve best with MySQL 8.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck with an oldish version of MySQL : 5.5.28.

Comment: As mentioned, the easiest approach is probably a stored function. I've found the following link where they have a function that sorts elements in a csv string, so obviously MySQL provides the functionality needed. You function will even be simpler...

Comment: http://psoug.org/snippet/mySQL-Sort-comma-separated-string_500.htm?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=a1208c062b7513b64630dbd958c22d0e1bc68a8a-1601378026-0-ARaRlOWon13C9nv41qv7-8NdPO4096BSF0TVE8ObmovUuWv3aL_78XzB6JntiLHcmHd9HRM1Itovt5xfu_egozwbEl1sCRFsEOX9LdawGULXIL8JXaxDF4duCBltDwhn9qKAKl129ONutF-RfDiPhDyWZQK4SltKEcumdcxOhgVk6xlJjiDK_cpEmHB3UHL46DIBSVcg_eb2pS7Y8igXgMJLzD5eIwV8YLyNrwmSNDwuax6NhRxSpcWnrTQ7m8VjBKnyNg_3EtLnFn2UyTzmySve6sFwSkTTZVqu3aOZKK87j63lgADCHBZtxMbWgi-1hHny88VflOHZ1Z82IxfkDfA

Answer (score 0):

This reads like a gaps-and -islands problem, where you want to group together "adjacent days" of the same month.

Here is an approach using window functions (this requires MySQL 8.0):

```
select 
    group_concat(case when min_dt = max_dt then min_dt else concat(min_day, '-', max_day) order by min_day separator ',') as days, 
    year, 
    month
from (
    select 
        date_format(tbl_contract_dates.date, '%Y') year, 
        date_format(tbl_contract_dates.date, '%M') month, 
        min(day(dt)) min_day,
        max(day(dt)) max_day
    from (
        select t.*, row_number() over(partition by year(date), month(date) order by date) rn
        from tbl_contract_dates t
        where contract_id = 34
    ) t
    group by year, month, date_format(date, '%Y-%m-01') - interval rn day
) t
group by year, month
```

The basic idea is to use the difference between the start of the month and the row number to build the groups. You can then aggregate by groups first, and then by month.

---

In earlier versions, we can emulate `row_number()` with a subquery; this will probably not scale well if you have a large dataset:

```
select 
    group_concat(case when min_dt = max_dt then min_dt else concat(min_day, '-', max_day) order by min_day separator ',') as days, year, 
    month
from (
    select 
        date_format(tbl_contract_dates.date, '%Y') year, 
        date_format(tbl_contract_dates.date, '%M') month, 
        min(day(dt)) min_day,
        max(day(dt)) max_day
    from (
        select t.*, 
            (
                select count(*) 
                from tbl_contract_dates t1 
                where t1.contract_id = t.contract_id and t1.date >= date_format(t.date, '%Y-%m-01') and t1.date <= t.date
            ) rn
        from tbl_contract_dates t
        where contract_id = 34
    ) t
    group by year, month, date_format(date, '%Y-%m-01') - interval rn day
) t
group by year, month
```

Comment: I was really hoping this would work, but of course it doesn't because of my version of MySQL : 5.5.28. I get `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by min_day separator ',') as days`

Comment: @Pat: I edited my answer with an approach for earlier versions

Answer (score 0):

I put some sample data into a WITH clause to create a playground.

The thing is not quite trivial: you have to work vertically for a while, and create an island-gaps pattern , or , as others call it, "sessionize" the date series, before you can create from-to literals. To keep the answer smaller, I just sessionize, and show the vertical rows, and leave it to you to GROUP_CONCAT() again ....

Here goes:

```
WITH
workdays(dt) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2020-08-08'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-08-10'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-08-11'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-08-12'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-08-16'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-09-20'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-09-27'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-09-28'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-09-29'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-09-30'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-10-01'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-10-02'
)
,
with_counter AS (
-- counter is 1 every time we have
-- more than one day as gap
  SELECT
    *
  , CASE WHEN LAG(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(dt) ORDER BY dt) + 1 < dt
           OR LAG(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(dt) ORDER BY dt) IS NULL
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS counter
  FROM workdays
)
,
with_session AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , SUM(counter) OVER(ORDER BY MONTH(dt), DAY(dt)) AS session
  FROM with_counter
)
-- test query ...
-- SELECT * FROM with_session;
-- out      dt     | counter | session 
-- out ------------+---------+---------
-- out  2020-08-08 |       1 |       1
-- out  2020-08-10 |       1 |       2
-- out  2020-08-11 |       0 |       2
-- out  2020-08-12 |       0 |       2
-- out  2020-08-16 |       1 |       3
-- out  2020-09-20 |       1 |       4
-- out  2020-09-27 |       1 |       5
-- out  2020-09-28 |       0 |       5
-- out  2020-09-29 |       0 |       5
-- out  2020-09-30 |       0 |       5
-- out  2020-10-01 |       1 |       6
-- out  2020-10-02 |       0 |       6

SELECT 
    CAST(MIN(DAY(dt)) AS VARCHAR(2))
  ||CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN ''
      ELSE '-'||CAST(MAX(DAY(dt)) AS VARCHAR(2))
    END
  AS daylit
, DAY(MIN(dt)) AS d
, MONTH(MIN(dt)) AS mn
, TO_CHAR(MIN(dt),'Month') AS mth
, YEAR(MIN(dt)) AS yr
FROM with_session
GROUP BY session
ORDER BY 3,2
;
-- out  daylit | d  | mn |    mth    |  yr  
-- out --------+----+----+-----------+------
-- out  8      |  8 |  8 | August    | 2020
-- out  10-12  | 10 |  8 | August    | 2020
-- out  16     | 16 |  8 | August    | 2020
-- out  20     | 20 |  9 | September | 2020
-- out  27-30  | 27 |  9 | September | 2020
-- out  1-2    |  1 | 10 | October   | 2020
```